# QTimer timeout and QMutex interaction

Tags: qt, qtimer, qmutex

Let's say we have some basic timer and a slot which is invoked periodically.

```
SomeObject::SomeObject()
{
  QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
  connect(timer , SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateState()));
}

void  SomeObject::updateState()
{
   // some operations leading to update of updatedValue
}
```

I also have function from same object which forces updates and returns some value.

```
bool  SomeObject::getLatestState()
{
  updateState();
  return updatedValue;
}
```

This function may be directly called from different threads. This brings question of thread safety to mind. Simple mutex lock in `getLatestState` will not help as in some rare cases `getLatestState` is called from another thread that starts `updateState`. And at the same time timer's timeout may occur. Can you help me handle this situation properly?

Comment: Put the mutex where you need protection. Here you need to protect `updatedValue`, so you need to put the mutex wherever you access it, so you need to put the mutex also in `updateState()`. You just have to take care you do not dead lock by relocking the mutex when you call `updateState()` from `getLatestState()`. Also you could use `QReadWriteLock` instead of `QMutex`

Comment: This is the part i wanted to avoid - as `updateState()` invokes a bunch of other stuff which also needs to be protected. It may almost be covered by stopping timer temporarily in `getLatestState`, but it will not prevent case where timeout is processing and `getLatestState` was invoked

Comment: If you don't want to use muted, then you have to use atomic variable and operations.

Comment: I think solution might be to remember the last time when `updateState` was called and skip update if it is too soon. This way i'll be able to only protect `updatedValue` in `getLatestState` and in `updateState` only new logic that prevents frequent updates. Without deadlocks

Comment: If you have a memory that can be accessed from different threads, you have to use either a locking system (mutex) or a atomic operations. You cannot get away with just having another variable to remember if it is too soon or not ; this variable will likely also be accessed from different threads. You are just pushing the problem further without solving it.

Answer (score 1):

[QMutexLocker can be used in such situations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html)

this my exampl

```
static QMutex mainMutex;
.....
MainController* MainController::s_instance = NULL;
.....    
MainController* MainController::getInstance()
{
    if(!s_instance){
        QMutexLocker lock(&mainMutex);
        if(!s_instance){
            s_instance = new MainController;
        }
    }
    return s_instance;
}
```

getInstance() function directly called from different threads.

Comment: I am aware about `QMutexLocker`, but it will not help in your situation if `MainController` will call `getInstance` periodically. Sooner or later it will deadlock when some other thread locks mutex before timeout

Comment: Doc Qt. t should be written in such a way that it always returns quickly (typically after processing one data item) so that Qt can deliver events to widgets and stop the timer as soon as it has done all its work. This is the traditional way of implementing heavy work in GUI applications; multithreading is now becoming available on more and more platforms, and we expect that zero-millisecond QTimers will gradually be replaced by QThreads.

Comment: The important thing about events is that they're not delivered as soon as they're generated; they're instead queued up in an event queue and sent sometime later. The dispatcher itself loops around the event queue and sends queued events to their target objects, and therefore it is called the event loop. Conceptually, this is how an event loop looks (see the Qt Quarterly ):

Comment: my example everything is written correctly, and works without a problem))

Comment: correct, but if you apply it to my case - when i call slot in the same thread by timeout and have possibilities of it being called by other threads - you will receive a deadlock

Comment: The important thing about events is that they're not delivered as soon as they're generated; they're instead queued up in an event queue and sent sometime later.)))

Comment: All in turn waiting)))

Comment: That's not how events are working in Qt. The fact that `Queued` connections are not instant does not make them `thread safe`. And in my example timeout is`Direct` connection which is executed `immediately` after timer fires up. And function `getLatestState` might be called directly or indirectly (via queued connections) by a bunch of other threads

Comment: in  Qt documentation:

Comment: For QTimer to work, you must have an event loop in your application; that is, you must call QCoreApplication::exec() somewhere. Timer events will be delivered only while the event loop is running.

In multithreaded applications, you can use QTimer in any thread that has an event loop. To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use QThread::exec(). Qt uses the timer's thread affinity to determine which thread will emit thetimeout() signal. Because of this, you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread.

Comment: Use  QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Comment: Invokes the member (a signal or a slot name) on the object obj. Returns true if the member could be invoked. Returns false if there is no such member or the parameters did not match.

Comment: Call the getLatestState()  function with  [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)